# How to configure or connect ejabberd 18 xmpp server to App server for push notifications ( XEP-0060 XEP-0357 )?

Tags: push-notification, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am using ejabberd 18 as xmpp server, to use push notification implementing mod_push, we need to connect ejabberd server to App server extending ejabberd 18, Is there any plugins or extensions available ? any other way to enable push notifications.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Jitin, I am also facing same issue, did you found and solution

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not possible to use some functionality like this out of the box in Ejabberd Community Edition

Check this page https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/ and you will see that all mobile P1-Spec extensions are available only at Business Edition

However, I believe you can do what you want with Community Edition following these steps:

- Implement new plugin for Ejabberd which will listen for messages and understand whether you opponent(s) is offline.
- If someone is offline - this plugin can make a request (HTTP) to you App Server API to initiate a push delivery

I did this flow for [Tigase XMPP Server](https://tigase.net/content/tigase-xmpp-server) and it works great for me, so I'm sure the same can be replicated for Ejabberd

Comment: Thank you so much, please let me know if any already developed (third party) plugins or extensions exist .

Comment: I do not know any, but will need it in future as well, so would be great to know as well

Answer (score 0):

The same question is also asked here: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2596

Comment: Yup that's also me..  :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

Ejabberd Community edition does not support push notification directly, one needs to write a custom module in erlang for that, But Ejabberd Saas and Business edition supports push notification directly, you'll just have to configure the settings.